# Twilio Conversation: SessionError: Channel not found when marking messages as read

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am using @twilio/conversations": "^1.2.3" nodejs package my project. I have a conversation which has two participants one is sms and the other is web. When I am calling setAllMessagesRead() I got error No channel found.

[image]

Both participants exist it still shows this error. It have lastMessage object but lastReadMessageIndex is null. Need help what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your channels are in "closed" state, which means you cannot make any modifications to them anymore.

The returned error is misleading, we will fix it.

Comment: There are coming in join event which they are not closed. If they are closed why they are showing up in join event.

Comment: Because Joined event is sent together with Added event if you have joined the channel.

Comment: But if you fetch the channel's state you will see it is 'closed'.

Comment: yes but when I close from rest api its status is notParticipating but in these one status is joined

Comment: We haven't mark them closed. If we close we receive conversationLeft event so that they won't appear in join event.

Comment: I do not know how they got closed, all I can see is that they are in the closed state now, and you will not be able to perform mutating operations on already closed conversations.

Comment: Yes I remove the participants manually , this is a twilio bug

Comment: Which part of this is a twilio bug in your opinion?

Comment: The conversation got closed automatically, no timer were set and status remains as joined. When we close with api status becomes notParticipating.